# I made code to calculate greatest common divisor but there is issue

Tags: java, math, printing, numbers, greatest-common-divisor

Hi people I made code to calculate greatest common divisor of 2 number.

It work good but I get many outputs. I want the greatest output but I don't know how to fix it?

What my code do is this here: You enter 2 integer. The first integer must be greater than the second. Now code check second integer first. Is it dividable by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .. Then code check all working numbers with first number. In the end we have greatest common divisor.

And before code does all it, it check if second number divide first (in case second is the gcd).

Now my problem: Let's take input 36 and 14. My code will give output

```
1
2
```

But how can I avoid code also print all other working numbers? I only want printed the greatest working number but no idea how to implement this in my code? I also don't want copy other code because I did all myself till here and proud:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testit{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double x = input.nextDouble();
        double y = input.nextDouble();
        double first=0;

        first=x/y;

        if(first==(int)first){
            System.out.println((int)y);
            return;
        }

        else{
            for(double i=1; i<x && i<y; i++){
                double sum=0;
                sum=y/i;

                if(sum==(int)sum){
                    double temp=0;
                    temp=x/i;
                    if(temp==(int)temp){
                        System.out.println((int)i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record ...as I gave you that first hint; consider upvoting my answer too please ... as soon as you reach upvote level. Uups, you just did ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat Hey cat I give you upvote now because yesterday I go training but now I make thank you again also for answer my other question!!

Comment: Feel free to upvote tomorrow. I already hit the daily cap today; on the other hand: just do what works for you. One upvote doesnt exactly matter ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing, save the result in a temporary variable

```
double first=0;
int greatestCommonDivisor = 1;
...
                if(temp==(int)temp){
                    greatestCommonDivisor = Double.valueOf(i).intValue();
                }
...
System.out.println("Greatest common divisor:" + greatestCommonDivisor);
```

That said, there are a lot of places your algorithm and code could be improved. For a start you should think about starting at the largest possible number and just stopping when you found the first common divisor (because that would be the greatest) instead of looping through all possible numbers starting from the smallest possible number. And you should have a look at the modulo operation and use integers instead of doubles for your values.

Comment: but no understand valueOf? i write gcd = ((int)i); instead and it work same

Comment: @mogulba That is because of auto-boxing. Where: your loop counter *i* should be of type **int** in the first place. Conceptually, it should **not** be a double in the first place. In other words: step back and look into what types you are using in the first place. FInally: UPPERCASE is perceived as SCREAMING in the internet. Thus: RUDE! Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your code; for example like this:

Currently, your code is simply printing each time it finds a "match".

Instead of printing immediately, you push that value into a **helper** variable. And in the end; when your loop has ended, you simply print that **helper** variable!

Then you automatically print the last number that your algorithm computed and stored.

( I am not giving you any code here; just an idea - as you will learn more by writing the code yourself! )

Comment: THANK YOU BUT NO LEARNED OTHER METHODS SO I CANT DO THIS BUT THANK YOU FOR HELP ME :)